# Optimal solution for flattening arrays within arrays

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Looking for an optimal solution .The structure I have is

```
Source a = {
        "key1": [
            [
                0
            ],
            [
                1
            ]
        ],
        "key2": [
            [
                2
            ],
            [
                3
            ]
        ]
    }
    Target=[0][1][2][3]
```

Is there any better solution than the following?

```
    a_values=a.values()
    flatValues=[]
    for i in range(0,len(a_values)):
        flatValues=flatValues+a_values[i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = {"key1": [[0],[1]], "key2": [[2],[3]]}
>>> target_generator = chain(*a.values())
>>> target_list = [v for v in target_generator]
>>> print(target_list)
[[0], [1], [2], [3]]
```

***N.B.*** `target_list` could possibly also look like this: `[[2], [3], [0], [1]]`

Comment: TigerhawkT3's answer [v for l in a.values() for v in l ] is also good.  Your code may raise error in Python3.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `[v for l in a.values() for sl in l for v in sl]` (or `[[v] for...`, if you really want a bunch of single-element lists for some reason) would be tidier. Note that it might not be sorted in the order you had in mind, so if that's important you may need to sort manually at some point (depending on your Python version and implementation).

Comment: Thanks..i am sorting it later though on other variables..the order is not priority...what i want to understand is ..apart from tider is this more performant?